# 3-3. Write a program to count how many times each distinct word appears in its input

Tags: c++, vector

In this:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>

using std::cout; using std::cin; using std::vector; using std::endl;
using std::string;

int main(){
    cout << "enter strings: " << endl;
    string s;
    vector<string> in;
    vector<string> out;
    vector<int> count;

    while(cin >> s)
        in.push_back(s);
    out.push_back(in[0]);
    count.push_back(1);

    int index = 0;
    for(int i=0;i<in.size();i++){
        if(out[index]==in[i])
            (count[index])++;
        
        else{
            out.push_back(in[i]);
            count.push_back(1);
            index++;
        }
     }

   cout << endl;
   for(int i=0;i<count.size();i++)
      cout << "i: " << i << "\tval: " << count[i] << endl;
}
```

I am not sure hot make the variable `index` to move *only* forward in `count` vector to count only those words that have already occure. Can someone help? exercise from book `Accelerated C++ Practical Programming by Example`

Comment: Read up about data structures.  In particular, you might want to consider using a [set](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/set/set/), which stores unique values only.  Or a [map](https://www.moderncplusplus.com/map/), which allows you to look up an item by a "key".

Comment: @paulsm4 that was not in the chapter yet. I want to use only the knowledge from previous chapters.

Comment: Do yourself a favor - DON'T adhere slavishly to some textbook by rote :(  ALSO: please read this link: [Understanding algorithm efficiency and why it’s important](https://medium.com/@humzah.choudry/understand-algorithm-efficiency-and-why-its-important-89df0d5dfb64)

Comment: @milanHrabos well, since we don't know what you are studying from, we don't know what chapters you have already covered, and thus we don't know the restrictions you have, so we can't answer your question.

Comment: you can't be incrementing `index` in the block where you're doing it (`else`). You want two loops, one that increments `index`, the other that increment `i`

Answer (score -2, accepted):

If you can't use `std::map`, you can associate the word with the frequency:

```
struct Info
{
  std::string word;
  int         frequency;
};

//...
std::vector<Info> database;
//...
std::string word;
while (std::cin >> word)
{
    // Find the word:
    const size_t length = database.size();
    for (unsigned int i = 0; i < length; ++i)
    {
      if (database[i].word == word)
      {
         database[i].frequency++;
         break;
      }
    }
    if (i >= length)
    {
        Info new_info{word, 0};
        database.push_back(new_info);
    }
}
```

The above code also shows that you should only insert words that are duplicates.  No need to input all the words, then do the processing.

Comment: This [doesn't compile](https://godbolt.org/z/TqWvc5).

Comment: @IInspectable Changed the `frequency` member from string to integer.  Please review (and upvote if acceptable).  Thanks.